# %systemroot%\system32\GroupPolicy gone

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, deployment

DC Win2012, Client XP

I have a couple of problems getting GPOs applied - well, they show up as getting applied (`gpresult`) but the software i tried to deploy didnt got deployed. I enabled userenv-logging by adding REG_DWORD `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\UserEnvDebugLevel` *0x10002* and got the following error:

**Local GPO's gpt.ini is not accessible, assuming default state.**

OK, googled that and finally found out that the folder *%systemroot%\system32\GroupPolicy* didnt exist. (How could this happen?)

So i just created that folder, but now i get the following error:

**GPO *Richtlinien der lokalen Gruppe*** (en: Local Group Policy?) **doesn't contain any data since the version number is 0.  It will be skipped.**

-.- What has happened and how can i fix this? What could stop Windows from just *creating* the missing structure? What are the effective ntfs-rights needed on that folder?